# Why will my notification sound alert not go off when go to the lock screen on my device and re-enter the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

I put in a notification into my app that works just right when I want it to go off. However I put a custom sound to that notification thats is about 30 seconds long. When I am at the HOME SCREEN of my device, when the the notification + sound goes off, I re-enter the app and the sound goes away. But when I am at the LOCK SCREEN, the notification goes off but when I re-enter the app it does not turn off. WHY

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can check the notification agent, whether the program allows notifications in the background.

Comment: What do you mean by checking to see if it allows notifications in the background? They do go off like normal notifications its just that the sound will not turn off when the device goes to the lock screen (the inactive state?), but works COMPLETELY great when its at the home screen. Is there a specific piece of code that works with the notification code i guess when it comes to the app going into the lock screen state?